# PHP Upload pdf file and replace the file name with a custom one

Tags: php

I have a problem, I can't get php to replace the name of the pdf with "$fiscale". I am a new php user and I would need a hand. Thanks to everyone for the possible answers: 3
(I am creating a site that allows you to upload pdfs with a name chosen at the beginning.)

php:

```
    <?php
    // per prima cosa verifico che il file sia stato effettivamente caricato
    if (!isset($_FILES['userfile']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
      echo 'File non caricato.';
      exit;    
    }
    
    //percorso della cartella dove mettere i file caricati dagli utenti
    $uploaddir = "uploads/"  . $_POST['fiscale'] . '.pdf';
    
    //recupero il nome originale del file caricato
    $userfile_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    
    $fiscale = $_POST['fiscale'];
    
    //copio il file dalla sua posizione temporanea alla mia cartella upload
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir)) {
      //Se l'operazione è andata a buon fine...
      echo 'File inviato con successo.';
        }else{
      //Se l'operazione è fallta...
      echo 'Upload NON valido!'; 
    }
    ?>
```

html:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
      Invia questo file: <input name="userfile" type="file">
      <input name="fiscale" type="text" placeholder="test">
      <input type="submit" value="Invia File">
    </form>
```

Comment: What result do you have? Are files being uploaded? Is the "upload" folder exists and writable for the webserver?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: file in /storage/ssd2/927/17323927/public_html/upload.php on line 17
Upload NON valido! (Upload not valid)

Comment: I think it should be $_FILES['userfile'], not 'file'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir)) {
```

instead of

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding your question**

I see several issues in your code:

1. Use `__DIR__` to properly define location of `uploads` directory
2. Check that directory exists and is writable
3. Unclear what `move_uploaded_file` does.

**Friendly advice**

You should definitely start using open source tools for your need. You might want to have a look at:

- A [router library](https://packagist.org/?tags=router) to properly handle different HTTP routes.
- An incoming HTTP request handling library (or even a [simple framework](https://packagist.org/search/?tags=framework) that comes with router, request handling, validation etc.)
- A [file system handling library](https://packagist.org/?tags=filesystem) to abstract from using FS directly.
- A [form validation library](https://packagist.org/search/?tags=form%7Evalidation) to validate user input (since it's **UNSAFE and INSECURE** to allow users define their own names for uploaded files **without validation**)

Use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/). Use contemporary tools.

Do everyone that comes after you, including your future self, a favor — use ready-made libraries to handle typical problems, most probably all your problems have been solved already and put into open source solutions.